# How to mock multiple call chained function with jest

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs

When i write unit test for my project,
i meet the case that i need mock a function chained multiple call in mongoose module.

if it only call .populate() once like code below:

```
await mongoose.model("routeDetail").find({
            _id: {
                $in: requestBody.routeIds,
            },
        })
            .populate("organizationId")
```

i could easily mock it such as
****mocks****/mongoose.js

```
module.exports = {
    model: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    find: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    populate: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    sort: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
};
```

**test**/myFile.test.js

```
mongoose.populate = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(myValue);
```

but...
In the other case that .populate() is called multiple time such as code below, i don't know how to mock it.

```
await mongoose.model("routeDetail").find({
            _id: {
                $in: requestBody.routeIds,
            },
        })
            .populate("organizationId")
            .populate("deliverDetail.orderInfo")
```

Anyone has idea?
Please help me resolve this case, many tks!

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. Mongoose has a complex API, abstract it behind an interface you _do_ own and mock _that_ for unit tests. Use integration tests to validate the actual queries.

Comment: i know about it, but i don't want refactor code at present because many reasons such as resources human,so I can just keep doing it

Answer (score 1):

For that specific example, you can mock the implementation:

```
const model = {
  find: jest.fn(() => ({
    populate: jest.fn(() => ({
      populate: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([])),
    })),
  })),
};
```

Model is an object that has a `find` function that returns an object with a `populate` function that returns an object with a `populate` function that returns a `Promise` that resolves an empty array.

Comment: So when there is second call which is model.find().populate() is also in same function, how can i mock it?

Comment: You just overwrite on each test, the implementation of the mock. On one test you are going to have find -> populate -> populate and in the other: find -> populate. it makes sense?

Comment: but 2 mongosse is called in one function, i can split to 2 case test.

Comment: I recommend you to encapsulate these calls on services. So the first mongoose call is going to be the result of first service, (something like simpleFind()) and the second mongoose call is going to be the result of the second service. (something like populatedFind()). By this way, you will mock different encapsulated pieces of code, and it will be much easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

in file .test.js, write code below on case test need to mock

```
    mongoose.populate = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        populate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({name:"mock value"})
    });
```

That's all. It worked for me

but in other cases, when a function contain 2 query mongoose that first query is

`find().populate().populate()`*(call   populate() twice )*

and the next is

`find().populate()` *(only call   populate() once )*

again, I have no idea to mock.